# Finding the energy stored in a 5uF capacitor

Tags: voltage, current, waveform

The current flowing through a 5uF capacitor is represented in the picture. Find the energy in the capacitor at t= 1.4ms, t = 3.3ms, t = 4.3ms, t = 6.7ms, and 5 = 8.5ms.

[image: Graph]

So ultimately we will use the formula: $$w = \frac{1}{2}cv^2$$ to find the voltage at each of the points of t.

But in order to get the voltage for the equation, we need to use the formula: $$v = \frac{1}{c}\int^{t}_{-\infty}i(t)dt $$

What I'm asking is if theres a specific way to go about taking the integrals throughout the waveform. Do I simply taking the integral from each change, such as 0 to 2, 2 to 4,and so on, creating a waveform from that, OR do I take the integral from 0 to t, which will be $$v = \frac{1}{5}\int^{t}_{0}\frac{15}{2}tdt$$ then looking at 2 to 4, we will have $$v = \frac{1}{5}(\int^{2}_{0}\frac{15}{2}tdt + \int^{t}_{2}15mA dt)$$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a math problem.

Comment: Yes, what you have is right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It looks  like homework

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an integral is just the area under the curve. So you can use basic geometry to find these integrals.

So, at 1.4 ms, for example, you just have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{1.4 \rm{ms}}i(t)dt = \frac{1}{2}(1.4\ \rm{ms})(10.5\ \rm{mA}) = 7.35\ \rm{\mu{}C}$$

using the formula for area under a triangle. (And assuming \$Q(t=0)\$ is 0)